# How do I stop LibreOffice Writer putting selected fonts at the top of the drop-down menu?

Tags: fonts, libreoffice-writer

Whenever I select a font in LibreOffice Writer, it gets prefixed to the top of the menu.

This wouldn't be a big deal if, when typing the name, it ignored the font at the top and skipped to it in the context of its related fonts - but it doesn't do that, and - when trying to experiment with different versions of fonts - I'm forced to remember the nearest differently named font and type but not select it just to get back to the general area.

What do I need to do to disable this behaviour, so fonts do not get prefixed and typing them always goes to the original position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling this behavior is pretty easy in LibreOffice Writer:

1. Choose the **Tools** ▸ **Options…** menu item
2. Navigate to the **View** page in the Options dialog
3. Unmark the **Show fonts history** check box.
4. Click **OK**. If the change does not apply immediately, restart the application.

[image: Screenshot of LibreOffice’s Options dialog]

---

**Edit:** In recent versions of LibreOffice, several Options pages have been simplified, and this option is no longer present. However, one can still edit this preference by going to the “**Expert Configuration**” dialog (**Tools** ▸ **Options** ▸ **LibreOffice** ▸ **Advanced**) and searching for the [preference](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94940) `org.openoffice.Office.Common > Font > View > History`.

Comment: Thank you. Thought I'd looked through all relevant preferences, but obviously missed this. Is a shame there isn't an Eclipse-style preferences filter or it'd have been easy to locate.